# Eclipse error. Insert curly bracket to complete class body but their is already a "}"

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello first time asking but this has always been a problem for me using eclipse. I already have a "}" but it keeps telling me their is a syntax error and i need a curly bracket at the end of this code. Changed it and it still does not work

```
package myprograms;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Programch5
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int Hoursworked;
        double Hourlyrate;
        String input;
        input=
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what is the" + "number of hours worked");
        Hoursworked= Integer.parseInt(input);

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what is the" + Hourlyrate);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you do need, you have 2 opening curly brackets but only 1 closing

Comment: There is no matching `}` for the `{` below the line `public class Programch5`

Comment: You have an empty '=' add something after input=

Answer (score 1):

You should add one more curly bracket to match the one on line 6. The existing curly bracket closes the one from line 8.

Comment: edit the original question and the errors still pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your first curly bracket at the end of public class Programch5

Comment: or you just need a refresh, I tried your codes and it works for me, I just initialized Hourlyrate

Answer (score 0):

You have not entered any string in input.

```
    package myprograms;
     import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
     public class Programch5 {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
     int Hoursworked; 
    double Hourlyrate;
     String input; input= "somestring";
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what is the" + "number of hours worked");
     Hoursworked= Integer.parseInt(input);
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what is the" + Hourlyrate); 

    } 

    }
```

Enter the string in double quotes and don't forget the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String input;
        input=
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what is the" + "number of hours worked");
```

> input=

What happen to this line of code? Complete it and it should work.